# Iterating limits with delta functions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

At least according to what I see in mathematica,
$\int_{t_{0}}^{t^{\prime}}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})+\int_{t^{\prime}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})\neq\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})$

By assuming $t_{0}=0, t>0$ for simplicity, $\int_{t_{0}}^{t^{\prime}}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})+\int_{t^{\prime}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})=2\theta(t_{1})-2\theta(t_{1}-t)+\theta(t_{1}-t)\theta(t-t_{1})$ while $\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})=\theta(t_{1})\theta(t-t_{1})$, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside theta function.

However, one might want to claim that $\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})=\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\epsilon}{(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}$ and then,
$\int_{t_{0}}^{t^{\prime}}dt^{\prime\prime}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\epsilon}{(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}+\int_{t^{\prime}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\epsilon}{(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}
=_{?}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\left(\int_{t_{0}}^{t^{\prime}}dt^{\prime\prime}\frac{\epsilon}{(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}+\int_{t^{\prime}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\frac{\epsilon}{(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\right)=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}dt^{\prime\prime}\delta(t^{\prime\prime}-t_{1})$.

Is the step where the $=_{?}$ sign is a valid one? in other words, do the conditions for interchanging these operations apply in this case?

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function.  As a measure, it operates on functions on $C_C$ using the Lebesgue integral under the Dirac measure.  And as a distribution, it operates on functions on $C_C^\infty$ as a linear functional, NOT an integral.  In either case of defining the Dirac Delta, the function $H(t-t_0)-H(t-t')$ is discontinuous at $t_0$ and $t_1$ and does not qualify.

Comment: Thank you Mark! what is $H$ in your response? assuming that the delta functions acts as a measure (meaning that there is an additional implicit compact support function), are these integrals entirely equivalent or not?

Comment: $H$ is the Heaviside (aka the unit step) function.  The issue is that if we use the Dirac measure and the Lebesgue integral, we need to be careful about the set over which we integrate.  One and only one set must contain $t'$.  So either, the first integral is over $[0, t']$ and the second is over $(t,',t]$, OR the first integral is over $[0, t')$ and the second is over $[t,',t]$.  Then, the sets combine as $[0,t]$.

Comment: I agree that your suggestion will fix the discrepecy, but in my case I cannot control over that, as these two integrals are a priori unrelated to each other (they are part of completely different expansions and I just later grouped them together). So, in both cases the integrations are supposed to be performed including the boundary points.